# Spring @ExceptionHandler - apply to json producing @RequestMapping only

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an exception handler like this that will produce a json error object to be consumed by javascript in the view.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController {


    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public final JsonResponse<Void> handleJsonException(
            final Exception e,
            final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return new ErrorJsonResponse(e);
    }

}
```

I don't want this method to run for regular postback (non json) requests.  So I would like to have these sorts of exception handled by the WEB.XML configured error pages.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/500</location>
</error-page>
```

In my @RequestMapping methods that return json I explicitly set the produces value.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dosomething",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

How can I tell spring to use a particular exception handler based on the produces content type?

Comment: As I remeber Spring `@ControllerAdvice` doesn't handle this type of HTTP errors, like 400, 401 and etc. I have these problem once, but I was able to turn over based com the URL pattern (every JSON request was called to `/api` context). You can try to redirect the location on web.xml to some `@Controller` and try to parse information about the request, after that thow a specific Exception that will catch on `@ControllerAdvice`

Comment: ExceptionHandler handles all exceptions that throw controller. So the only way I see is to move error page inside your application and to choose which page to return inside ExceptionHandler method. You may use HttpServletRequest for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

`@ControllerAdvice` annotated classes assist all known controllers in the application. Developers usually restrict ExceptionHandlers to some cases using specific business/technical exceptions; in that case, `Exception.class` is too broad.

But your use case is valid - in fact, this issue has been resolved (see [SPR-10222](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10222)) for the upcoming Spring 4.0 release.

You could for example have a RestExceptionHandlerController annotated with `@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)` - given your REST Controllers are annotated with `@RestController` (annotation that implies `@ResponseBody` on all methods!).

However, this new feature doesn't rely on MediaTypes (negotiated at runtime, depending on the client's request) but on annotations, assignabletypes, packages, base package classes... I think those could help you structure your `@ControllerAdvice` annotated classes.